# getDrawingCache on listView is very slow(60ms)

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, listview, android-view

I need to display a Lisview on a canvas.
What i do is use mListView.scrollListBy to scroll the list problematically and then i call mListView.getDrawingCache() method to takes "Snapshots" of a listview and draw them on a canvas.

```
    mListView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        mListView.buildDrawingCache();
        if (mListView.getDrawingCache() != null) {
            c.drawBitmap(mListView.getDrawingCache(), 0, 0, null);
        }
        mListView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        mListView.destroyDrawingCache();
```

I am experiencing a very slow frame rate(8-14 fps) So i timed this part and i see the c.drawBitmap only takes up about 8ms(I am using ARGB_8888 so its reasonable) but the first get call to get the drawing cache can take up to 80ms(up to 5 fps!!!).
I have tried to remove the buildDrawingCache line but then the 80ms comes in the if statement.
Is there any way to optimize the performance of this? are if not is there anyway to subclass the listView and just preform this action in the scrollListBy function?
Thanks ahead.

Comment: Why are you drawing a ListView on a canvas?

Comment: I am using a class which gives me a canvas for drawing

Comment: Then perhaps you should use the actual `Canvas` APIs for drawing.

Comment: You mean not using list view at all?